# Can I install Arch-Linux in my hard disk partition running archlinux iso in a VirtualBox?

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox

I am running arch Linux in my oracle VirtualBox and learning to install with arch wiki documentation.
 I was wondering if following things were possible to perform:

**First I have done following things**

- downloaded the iso
- running it in Oracle VirtualBox

**Now can I do following things?**

- Install Arch Linux in one of my hard disk partition through the virtual machine.
- Also after the installation I want it to appear in the grub so that next time I can have parallet operating system.

**I have partitioned the hardisk with gparted earlier for ubuntu so there is an empty partition to install arch**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would be *much* simpler to just boot into the live medium and do the install from there. Trying to do it from VirtualBox just adds an unecessary layer of complexity for zero benefit...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible with Virtualbox, by mapping the physical partition with a VMDK file.

It is not possible via the GUI, but it can be done via the VBoxManage command.

Below link might help:

http://www.sysprobs.com/access-physical-disk-virtualbox-desktop-virtualization-software